# pycharm, p3.6 running error :"D:\Python\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'D:/Python projects/Projects'

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.7

Whenever I click run in pycharm, it returns the following error:

```
"D:\Python\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'D:/Python projects/Projects'

Process finished with exit code 1"
```

the images below are my pycharm settings, Please help me, sos!

[img1 run error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8g8D.png)

[img2 project interpreter setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NTjn.png)

[img3 project structure setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nla4a.png)

[img4 debugs configuration setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atlzv.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to set script path as a path to test1.py (not to a "Projects" folder) in the debug configuration.

Comment: Ah, I see! Do I have to change the script path every time I open a new file or is there a method to automatically change the script path while I switch files?

Comment: In pycharm there is a possibility to add run configuration for every file (please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html). PyCharm supports multiple running configurations in one project. The simplest way to create one is when you have a new file perform right click on code editor and select "Run <your_file_name>".

Comment: Please remember switching files does not switch running configuration so if you want to switch configuration you have to either switch configuration (top right part of screen) or you can press Ctrl + F9 (this will switch to a configuration of a file that you currently have on the screen).